# How can I extract columns in perl and put into separate files?

Tags: perl

I have the following data consisting of tab-delimited data with double columns although the first three columns are not part of each doublet:

```
Name    Type    Pos HX-20_4218.txt.Geo A Position   HX-20_4218.txt.Geo B Position   HX-474_3712.txt.Geo A Position  HX-474_3712.txt.Geo B Position  HX-549_3943.txt.Geo A Position  HX-549_3943.txt.Geo B Position
A-2345252   1   5   0.3574  0.9796  0.3178  0.9641  0.5564  1.0000
A-1969580   1   7   -0.3777 1.0000  -0.6987 1.0000  0.1007  0.9696
....
```

I need to extract info from this to give the following tab-delimited output:

1st file: `HX-20.txt`

```
Name    Type    Pos HX-20_4218.txt.Geo A Position   HX-20_4218.txt.Geo B Position
A-2345252   1   5   0.3574  0.9796
A-1969580   1   7   -0.3777 1.0000
....
```

2nd file: `HX-474.txt`

```
Name    Type    Pos HX-474_3712.txt.Geo A Position  HX-474_3712.txt.Geo B Position
A-2345252   1   5   0.3178  0.9641
A-1969580   1   7   -0.6987 1.0000
....
```

3rd file: `HX-549.txt`

```
Name    Type    Pos HX-549_3943.txt.Geo A Position  HX-549_3943.txt.Geo B Position
A-2345252   1   5   0.5564  1.0000
A-1969580   1   7   0.1007  0.9696
....
```

How can I do this with perl?

Comment: Perhaps you should explain what your input is. I assume tab delimited data, with double columns ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like:

```
open my $in, '<', $filein or die $!
open my $out1, '>', $fileout1 or die $!
open my $out2, '>', $fileout2 or die $!
open my $out3, '>', $fileout3 or die $!

while(<$in>) {
    chomp;
    my @cols = split(/\t/, $_);
    my $line1 = join("\t", (@cols)[0..4]);
    my $line2 = join("\t", (@cols)[0..2,5,6]);
    my $line3 = join("\t", (@cols)[0..2,7,8]);
    print $out1 $line1,"\n";
    print $out2 $line2,"\n";
    print $out3 $line3,"\n";
}
```

Comment: Wrong mode on the output file handles.

Comment: How can this be generalized to case where multiple columns and correspondingly, multiple files to spit out. Also (sorry for complete lack of Perl knowledge) but how can I make `$filein` an argument to the script. Also, doesn't this mean I have to manually provide the names of the `$fileout` s. I don't want to do that. I want to be able to use part of the column header to name the output files. For e.g. `HX-20.txt` from the first two columns of `HX-20_4218.txt.Geo A Position   HX-20_4218.txt.Geo B Position`